# Not able to change nested div in javascript dom

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to javascript and I am facing problems in dynamically changing the onclick attribute of the anchor tag in html. Below is my code:

```js
function changeImage(){   

    var charAll = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['char_all']); ?>;

    var charCount = 0;

    for (var key in charAll) {
      
 var charDiv = document.getElementById(key);
   
 var anchorTag = charDiv.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

        anchorTag.onclick = function(){startChar('1', charAll[key].toString());};
   }
}
```

```html
<ul id="portfolio-list" data-animated="fadeIn">

    <li id="character1">
  <img src="character1.jpg" width="250px" height="280px" alt="" />
  <div class="portfolio-item-content">
   <span class="header">Play!</span>
   <p class="body"></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" onclick="startChar('1', '1')"><i class="more">></i></a>

  <div class="post-info">
   <div class="post-basic-info">
    <h3 class="text-center">Character 1</h3>
   </div>

  </div>

 </li>
 
 <li id="character2">
  <img src="character2.jpg" width="250px" height="280px" alt="" />
  <div class="portfolio-item-content">
   <span class="header">Play!</span>
   <p class="body"></p>
  </div>
  <a href="#" onclick="startChar('1', '1')"><i class="more">></i></a>

  <div class="post-info">
   <div class="post-basic-info">
    <h3 class="text-center">Character 2</h3>
   </div>

  </div>
  
 </li>

</ul>
```

What I intend on doing is to change the onclick function of each of the `<li>` elements. The session variable `$_SESSION['char_all']` is a dictionary in php, where the key is the character name (string) and the value is the character id corresponding to the character name in my database  table. So, ideally the `<a>` tags under the `<li>` tags should get the onclick attribute of `startChar('1', '1')` (for character 1) and `startChar('1', '2')` (for character 2). But, what I end up with is `startChar('1', '2')` for both the characters.

Where am I going wrong? It might be something very silly that I am overlooking. But, I am not able to figure out. So, please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

Your `for in` procedure referes to `key` which changes while iterating thorugh `charAll`. 
As a solution (not tested), you might want to wrap the function in an outer anonymous-function and pass `key` to it:

```
(function(currentKey) {
    anchorTag.onclick = function(){startChar('1', charAll[currentKey].toString());};
})(key);
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot :D. But, I am not understanding why this would work and not my code? Could you please explain?

Comment: For every iteration in the for-loop, the variable `key` is overwritten. In my solution you pass `key` to an anonymous function and preserve its value inside.